# useLoaderData must be used within a data router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-roter-dom v 6.4.2. I want to use useLoaderData in my home page like this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLoaderData } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {
  try {
    const user = useLoaderData();
    console.log(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>This is Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

and I'm using loader in Route component, like this:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './components/About';
import Products from './components/Products';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Home from './components/Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header></Header>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path='/'
          loader={async ({ request }) => {
            // loaders can be async functions
            const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", {
              signal: request.signal,
            });
            const user = await res.json();
            return user;
          }}
          element={<Home/>}
        ></Route>
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
        <Route path='/about' element={<About></About>}></Route>
        <Route path='/products' element={<Products></Products>}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But this showing an error:
**useLoaderData must be used within a data router.**
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7):

You have to use [`RouterProvider`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.0/routers/router-provider) component. It is a self closing component and takes a `router` prop, which is created by the [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router) function.

On `createBrowserRouter` function you can pass an array of objects (each one represending a route). Alternatively, you can pass the [`createRoutesFromElements`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/create-routes-from-elements) function which takes your routes as JSX and *translates* them into route objects (in this case your parent component should be a `Route` and not `Routes` and it has to return an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) in order to render it's child route elements)

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-https-o6u65d) is a sandbox demonstrating your example.

Comment: I know that. But I want to create it by BrowserRouter component, can I do this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. According to docs you must use `RouterProvider` in order to enable rest of the apis. Is there a particular reason why you want to stick to `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: Actually I feel comfortable with BrowserRouter component. By the way thank you.